# Regex to dynamically replace text in java

Tags: java, regex

What I am trying to do is make something like:

```
some random stuff substitute("random stuff","xxx") test
```

be replaced to the following:

```
some xxx test
```

If I use:

```
substitute\((.*?)*\)
```

I get to find the portion, but what I ultimately want is multiple groups where the first group is the text to search and the second group is to replace. I want it to be generic enough so I dont depend on the `,` since it can appear anywhere. Is there a regex that could work for all cases or should I be depending on the "" to get what I need?

Comment: Do you need a single regex? Seems it would be easier to first find the `substitute(...)` part, then do the substitution it specifies in a second call, then remove the `substitute(...)` bit.

Comment: You cannot use the ``replace`` method of String

Comment: I can do it in two steps. What I am really confused is how to get the first and second parameters easily, specially if the parameters can contain anything, commas, (), etc.

Comment: I think to do it in just one step you will need to use _forward reference_ by _backtracking_, but it would be one exhaustive task.

Comment: _or should I be depending on the "" to get what I need?_ If it is simple to achieve, then to get the parameters will be easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't have tested it but you could try

```
\w*\(\"(.*)\".*\"(.*)\"\)
```

If order in substitute doesn't change you have in your first group the search and in second the replace term.
And yes I don't see another way but depending on () and "".

Comment: Thanks Ben. Need to test it more for different combinations, but seems to do the trick on basic testing. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: I made some slight changes to account for spaces before and after the specific characters that are critical, but the approach in general works perfectly. Once again thanks for your help.